# Add sub categories to a Dependency Property in a Workflow Activity

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation, dependency-properties, workflow-activity

I wish to create an workflow activity that has a dependancy property structure like this

- Setting

  - Wait Period

    - Days
    - Hours
    - Mins

At the moment the code below will show **Setting** with the **Wait Period** as an Integer, but now need to expand it out to 3 sub child properties for **Days**, **Hours** and **Mins**.

I understand i will have to change the **Wait Period**, but i'm not sure how to go about attaching the other 3 properties to it.

Any help would be appreciated... Thanks.

```
public static DependencyProperty WaitPeriodProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WaitPeriod", typeof(int), typeof(CheckActivity));
/// <summary>
/// Dependency property for 'Wait Period'
/// </summary>   
///        
[DescriptionAttribute("The email of the sender")]
[CategoryAttribute("Settings")]        
public int WaitPeriod
{
    get
    {
        return (int)(base.GetValue(CheckActivity.WaitPeriodProperty));
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetValue(CheckActivity.WaitPeriodProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should definitely change the type from `int` to `TimeSpan`.  That has Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds.

The input UI may not be to your liking though its just a string:  d.hh:mm:ss.msecs

However personally I would put up with that for the simplicity of using a Type specifically designed for the task.  It might be possible to create a Custom editor for it though.